# ¿Cómo usar la funcion binom.lrt de R para una gran cantidad de registros?

Tags: r, funciones, archivo, manejo-de-memoria, rstudio

Estoy usando la función `binom.lrt` para calcular un intervalo de confianza con ciertas columnas de un archivo de texto, hice una prueba con 10 registros y obtengo el resultado sin problemas, pero cuando lo hago con 3 millones de registros, para la consola no se envía ningún mensaje de error y no recibo respuesta, he probado con otros intervalos del paquete `Proportion` y he obtenido resultados en aproximadamente 15 minutos para el mismo número de registros, que es lo que esta pasando?

El código es:

```
dirtem=c("C:/XXX2018")
temporal <- fread(dirtem, select = c(10,12,14))

temporal[, c("sumacasilla") := list(V10+V12)]
temporal[, c("new1","new2","new3","new4","new5","new6") := binom.lrt(V10,sumacasilla,0.90)]
temporal[,c("new7"):=ifelse((new5<V14 & V14<new6)=='TRUE',0,1)]                 
ans<-temporal[,.(new5,new6,new7)]
     new5       new6    new7
1  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
2  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
3  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
4  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
5  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
6  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
7  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
8  0.01701641 0.9829836 0
9  0.20716820 0.9927937 0
10 0.01701641 0.9829836 0
```

Comment: Bienvenido @G.C.Rodriguez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Es aconsejable cuando se habla sobre rendimiento computacional, dar un detalle del equipo dónde se ha ejecutado el código -procesador, memoria ram, Sistema operativo, etc.- No obstante hay un límite específico para la longitud (número total de elementos) para cualquier vector, matriz, array, columna en un cuadro de datos o lista. Esto se debe a un índice de 32 bits que se utiliza en **R**. El número es 2 ^ 31 - 1, es decir algo más de 2mil millones, superior a los 3 millones que se expone. Asimismo puedes tener más detalle en `?help(Memory-limits)` y `?help(Memory)`

Comment: Al ver el código también he notado rápidamente que `(new5<V14 & V14<new6)` es una expresión `booleana` y al compararla con un texto `'TRUE'` si bien va dar `TRUE` o `FALSE` (`TRUE=='TRUE'`) como va en una condición `ifelse` se puede omitir, pero en este caso particular como el resultado será `0` o `1` puedes cambiar `ifelse((new5<V14 & V14<new6)=='TRUE',0,1)`simplemente por `1*(new5<V14 & V14<new6)`.

Comment: Algo adicional del código es que ya no está presente en R el operador `:=` Supongo que lo empleas para aumentar la compatibilidad con C, Java u otro lenguaje... o qué versión de *R* es?, lo único que se me ocurre es que estes incluyendo en el ambiente global dicho operador: `":=" <- "<-" t:=0; t; # se imprime 0`. Nota los símbolos `:=` y `<-` que van entre " " debe ir entre: *`* comillas simples oblicuas: CODIGO ASCII 96